# Import, modify, reimport! Problems with code structure (python)

Tags: python, import, global-variables

Consider the following code, where I execute main.py file.

> #### settings.py
>
> ```
> MAX_A = 10
> R_SEED = 3
> ```
>
> #### utils.py
>
> ```
> from settings.py import *
>
> def exemple():
>     print MAX_A
> ```
>
> #### main.py
>
> ```
> from settings.py import *
> from utils.py import *
>
> MAX_A = 11
> print MAX_A # It prints 11
>
> # Function from utils
> example() # It prints 10
> ```
>
> #### Output
>
> ```
> > 11
> > 10
> ```

I would like to find a way to change the value of MAX_A from the main.py file and it alters the initial value of the variable for any other file that imports it.

I understand that the import I do on utils.py rewrite the variable's value. I also tried using global variables, but I couldn't find a way around.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import `*`. It does not do what you think it does. And it creates other problems as well.

Anyway, here's what  happens:

Since settings.py contains two variables: `MAX_A` and `R_SEED`, then these are the same:

```
from settings import *
from settings import MAX_A, R_SEED  # same thing, but better
```

The latter is better because you know what you are importing. `from settings.py import *` is simply wrong, BTW.

Now, `from settings import MAX_A, R_SEED` is almost the same as the following:

```
import settings
MAX_A = settings.MAX_A
R_SEED = settings.R_SEED
```

What it does is it creates local variables `MAX_A` and `R_SEED`, which are initialized to the values from `settings.py`.

To actually modify values in `settings`, you must not make copy variables.

```
import settings

print(settings.R_SEED)  # always read from variable in settings

settings.R_SEED = 11    # always write to variable in settings
```

Comment: Well, then! I hope I don't get to the point I need to import too many variables.

Thank you for your answer.